# Can I have multiple team members in the Presidential Suite in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I recently got a "hideout" in New Vegas.  Victor, the robot, alludes to the Presidential Suite as a "hideout" for my "friends"...as in plural.  The suite seems to have multiple rooms, and I know I've met multiple people on my journey that will join me as a teammate, but so far I've seen where I can only have one at a time, and I need to drop one in order to pick up another.  Does the presidential suite allow me to "store" teammates there?  Is there any way to have multiple teammates stored there, even if I can only take one out and about with me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If you tell your current companion that you'd like to part ways, you can send them back to the Lucky 38 to wait until you need them again. You can recruit every NPC companion in the game on one save file, and they'll all chill in the Lucky 38 until you pick them up.

Comment: Ok, so parting ways sends them to the Lucky 38, and not "I'm done with you and forfeit your quests" like I was afraid of.  Thanks, Fizz!

Comment: They'll give you a choice: you can send them back to either the Lucky 38 or where you first met them. Your choice.  Either way, it does not break their quests or otherwise alienate them. (though there are ways of doing that for several companions!)

Comment: Oh wow! This is great! :)